# How can I use asset select modal in utility?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, control-panel, garnish

[image]

I created a custom utility template. Inside the template, I would like to use the built-in asset select modal for the "Add image" button. Any way to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is just a normal `ElementSelect` field with the element type `craft\\elements\\Asset`

```twig
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
    label: "Asset"|t('app'),
    id: 'assetSelect', 
    name: 'assetSelect',
    elementType: 'craft\\elements\\Asset',
   selectionLabel: "Choose"|t('app'),
   elements: elements, //array of selected elements 
 }) }}
```

Comment: @ Robin Schambach Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. When we select an image, there is a modal popping up, we can search in the search bar at the top and when we scroll down to the bottom, we'll get more images. I need the exactly same modal as this. Many thx!

Comment: Yeah and the script will add a button to open this modal

Comment: Can I ask one more question please? Do you know how to limit the asset source?
At the back-end, I get the volumeId and in the twig elementselectfield, I code like this `sources: ['volumeId:'~volumeId]`. But it's not working

Comment: Include the property `criteria` with the properties for your element query. `criteria: {volumeId: 1, folderId: y}`